# dropdown list php with selected value from database

Tags: php, mysql

i have been working on a dropdown box in php where it links to tables profile_staff and potential_client the table structure is as below

table 1 - potential_client

pc_id | pc_staff
   1  | prav

table 2 - profile_staff
staff_id | staff_name
    1    | shree
    2    | prav

where the populated value should be from the table profile_staff column staff_name and the selected value should the value from potential_client column staff_id. below is the code i have done so far. its showing null value in the dropdown. please advise.

```
<?php  
$sql2 = "SELECT profile_staff from potential_client WHERE pc_id = '$pc_id'";
$sql1= "SELECT staff_name from profile_staff";

$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

echo '<select name="pc_staff">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1) && $row1 =      mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
if ($row === $row1) {
echo '<option value="' . $row . '" selected="selected" />';
} else {
echo '<option value="' . $row1 . '" />';
}
}
echo '</select>';  ?>
```

Comment: Both table have any relation with the parent child id if yes then can you describe details about the table structure more efficiently.

Comment: try using the actual fields within the rows ($row1{"staff_name"} and $row2{"profile_staff"}) rather than the row variables themselves - they are arrays containing different fields and different values, they won't be comparable and they won't populate your HTML without referencing the specific field(s) you want.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys here is the working code.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT staff_name FROM profile_staff";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<select name='pc_staff' <option value = '0'> Select Staff </option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($row['staff_name'] == $search_user['pc_staff']) {
    $selectCurrent=' selected';
echo '<option value="'.$search_user['pc_staff'].'"  '.$selectCurrent.'>'.$search_user['pc_staff'].'</option>';
}
else
 {
echo "<option value='" . $row['staff_name'] ."'>" . $row['staff_name'] ."  </option>";
  }
 }
 echo "</select>"; ?>
```